# How does linux virtual machine in windows use GPU in workstation?

Tags: docker, deep-learning, computer-vision, virtual-machine, gpu

Recently I have a framework which can run in Linux only, but I am used to work on windows.I know that Nvidia-docker doesn't support windows, so I have to choose install double system in one host or use a virtual machine allocated as Linux.Maybe I prefer the latter.So I want to know if the virtual machine can use GPU in host or in workstation? What should I do to solve this problem? Better method hoped! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For VMWare: https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln288103/how-to-enable-a-vmware-virtual-machine-for-gpu-pass-through?lang=en

And Hyper-V also can pasthrough GPU: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b9e21b8f-8774-49c2-b499-b2b8ff2a41a2/hyperv-windows-10-pci-passthrough?forum=win10itprovirt

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I konw the both can use GPU of host.Additionally, can Hyper-V or VMWare of my PC use the GPU in server? How?